# Is the master branch of symfony production ready?

Tags: symfony

I use the 2.0.x version in my project, but recently I've started to see more and more bundles that support **only** the master branch

Should I migrate to the master branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not stable and may contain unfinished code. Also, there are a lot of break changes that haven't been documented yet. If you're starting a new project, then go for master, if you have already written some code, I'd better wait for the next 2.1 release (all bundles should support it).

Most popular bundles work with 2.0 too, but you must often use the branch for your symfony version, not a bundle's master branch.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that some bundles doesn't offer an alternate branch for 2.0.x compatilibity (for eg: https://github.com/jmikola/JmikolaAutoLoginBundle).

Comment: @Madarco then there's no choice - you have to use master branch ;(

Comment: I'm waiting too a decision about https://groups.google.com/d/topic/symfony-devs/QaVf-QU80JU/discussion